# Automatically Copying Value & Format - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Automatically Copying one/many cell's value & colour format to another cell/range of cells specified by myself. The other cell also needs to update every time the first cell changes its value or format.

I've been able to see just one or two threads with answers to this question but it still doesn't serve my purpose. Can any genius help me out in here? I don't quite understand why a basic thing like this has taken me 1 full day to figure out  (the answer shouldn't be that I'm not smart :D)

Attaching an Excel example of what I want to achieve.

I want to be able to;

1. Update the Sheet 2 with the data from Sheet 1. (C4 in sheet 2 has to be green and have the value 5). Also, if C4 in Sheet 1 changes its value and colour, I want C4 in Sheet 2 to change automatically)
2. Now, the above is not only my concern. I have many cells in Sheet 1 which I want to be able to select and have them copied into Sheet 2 in respective places. (eg - c4, d4,e4 from sheet 1 ,.etc to be copied into c4, d4, e4 in sheet 2). Not necessarily I would want to choose the cells in a sequential fashion, but if there's a way for me to specify which cell needs to be copied into which cell of the other sheet, I'll be even more convinced.

   ```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
       Dim ping As Boolean
       If Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Then
       If ping = False Then
           Range("A3").Copy
           Range("C10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
       End If
          ping = True
          Exit Sub
       Else
          ping = False
       End If
    End Sub
   ```

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be with a user defined function. I could not try the code, but just to show the idea:

```
Public Function CopyFromTo(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    Application.Volatile True ' "A volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet"
    rngFrom.Copy rngTo
    CopyFromTo = rngFrom ' I am not sure what the function should return 
End Function
```

For example, formula in cell B2 would be `=CopyFromTo(A2, B2)`

Comment: Thanks for trying Slai. Doesn't seem to work though.